# Prove the theorem by using natural deduction in propositional logic. Is it right to use De Morgan laws?

Tags: propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

[image: Here you can see my attempt]
I am attempting to prove $$[(p\vee q)\wedge(r\vee s)]\to[(p\wedge r)\vee(p\wedge s)\vee(q\wedge r)\vee(q\wedge s)]$$ by natural deduction.  Above you can see the work I have made progressing on this proof.  Can I use the De Morgan Laws to get a contradiction?

Comment: Usually, De Morgan's laws are not included into the set of [Natural Deduction rules](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4).

Comment: If the exercise is about ND, I imagine that you have to use ND rules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you do have DeMorgan laws, you probably don't "have" that you can distribute the negation across four disjunctions.

If I were doing it, I would choose a strategy more like this.  (This is only part of the proof, but it gives you a sense of how you would need to proceed.)

[image]

Comment: aaaah, thank you!!!

Comment: sorry, why we should assume q and get p&q? where you take p&q?

Comment: And how to prove in the opposite direction like [(p ∧ r) ∨ (p ∧ s) ∨ (q ∧ r) ∨ (q ∧ s)] → [(p ∨ q) ∧ (r ∨ s)], I get this, but I don't know what should I assume. I tried to assume ¬(p v q), and then assume p and r particularly, but contradiction wasn't reached((( idk what is wrong. Here you can see my attempt https://wampi.ru/image/6tRuzZE

Comment: @same thing, where you prove $p\vee q$ and $r\vee s$ by $\vee E$ from each of the four pieces of the antecedent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $\lor$-elimination, which is in my book:

1. $p \lor q$
2. $p \to s$.
3. $q \to s$.
4. $s$ (from elimination and 1,2,3)

So I'd start the following way, there are no real choices what to do anyway:

1. $(p\lor q) \land (r \lor s)$ ass. to get the right hand side (and the full  statement, I'll write RHS for the disjunction with the 4 terms from now on) and the full statement.
2. $p \lor q$ from $\land$-elim. from 1.
3. $r \lor s$ from $\land$-elim. from 1.
4. $p$ ass. for $\to$ to use in $\lor$-elim.
5. $r$ ass.
6. $p \land r$ from $\land$-I; and 4,5.
7. RHS in three steps using $\lor$-I and 6.
8. $r \to \text{RHS}$ drop ass. 5, from $\to$-intro.
9. $p \to (r \to \text{RHS})$ from $\to$-I drop ass 4.
10. $q$ ass. for $\to$ to use in $\lor$-E.
11. $r$ ass.
    12 $q \land r$ $\land$-I; 10,11
12. RHS again from 3 times $\lor$-I.
13. $r \to \text{RHS}$ drop 11, $\to$-I.
14. $q \to (r \to \text{RHS})$ from $\to$-I drop ass 10.
15. $r \to \text{RHS}$ from $\lor$-E on 2,9,14.

Now do $s \to \text{RHS}$ in a similar way and apply $\lor$-E on 3,16 and that.
We get RHS directly.

Note that this proof just checks the 4 cases on the disjunctions 2 and 3, essentially.